# GEE- Calculating Burned Area Index for Sentinel 2 (Filipponi et al. 2018) but getting binary result than index range

Tags: google-earth-engine, sentinel-2, spatial-index, vegetation-index

I am trying to calculate BAIS2 index for sentinel-2 collection over a study area in Google Earth Engine. I tried to create a function using expression but end result is binary image rather than index with max and min value. Why its like that and how can I get index?
[link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmonish_d%2Fgee%3ABAI2)

```
var geometry:https://code.earthengine.google.com/?asset=users/monish_d/MP
var s2= ee.ImageCollection("COPERNICUS/S2_SR").filter(ee.Filter.lt("CLOUDY_PIXEL_PERCENTAGE", 10));
var vis = {bands: ['B4', 'B3', 'B2'], max: 2000, gamma: 1.5};
var area = ee.FeatureCollection(geometry); var opacity = 0.5; Map.centerObject(area, 6.5);
var ImCol = ee.ImageCollection(s2.filterDate('2020-02-15','2020-02-28') //// Filter by dates
.filterBounds(area)); 
//// Creat a Cloud Mask.
function maskS2sr(image) {
var cloudBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(10).int(); ////cloud band
var cirrusBitMask = ee.Number(2).pow(11).int();//// cirrus band
var qa = image.select('QA60'); //// Get the pixel QA band.
.and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cirrusBitMask).eq(0)); ////  Flags set to zero for clear conditions. return 
image.updateMask(mask) //// Return the masked image, scaled to TOA reflectance, without the QA bands.
 .copyProperties(image, ["system:time_start"]);
};
//// Apply cloud mask to image collections
var CM_ImCol = ImCol.map(maskS2sr);
////Fire Indices to add in image collections
var addBAI2= function(image) {
var B4 = image.select(['B4']);
var B6 = image.select(['B6']);
var B7 = image.select(['B7']);
var B8A = image.select(['B8A']);
var B12 = image.select(['B12']);
return image.addBands(image.expression('(1-((sqrt(B6*B7*B8A)/B4))*(B12-B8A)/((sqrt(B12+B8A)))+1)',
{B4: B4, B6: B6, B7: B7, B8A: B8A, B12: B12}).rename('BAI2'));
 };
 //// add bands to image collections
var fire_ImCol = CM_ImCol.map(addBAI2);
////Mosaic and clip images
var fire_mos = fire_ImCol.mosaic().clip(area);
////Fire Indices
var bai = {bands: ['BAI2'], max:1, min: -1}; 
Map.addLayer(fire_mos, bai,'Pre-fire BAI2');
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and has syntax errors in it.   Please post a link to the complete code.

Comment: [link](https://code.earthengine.google.com/?scriptPath=users%2Fmonish_d%2Fgee%3ABAI2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look more closely at the **BAIS2** formula in [Filipponi's work](https://www.mdpi.com/2504-3900/2/7/364/pdf), you will see that expression in your code is not reflecting it. I suggest that you fix it before whatever later analysis. However, I can use your original formula for searching where your issue is. If you look at [metadata](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S2_SR) of **COPERNICUS_S2_SR** product, you will see that bands used in your expression need to be divided by 10000. I know that by using your expression without divided bands and Inspector Tab; as in following picture. BAI2 values are abnormally too high.

[image]

After dividing bands by 10000 and by using other visualization parameters, I got following result in this [new version](https://code.earthengine.google.com/acb86e51545fa4345296fb7189d4bc15) of your code. It can be observed a new "texture" in your image and BAI2 were drastically reduced to values between 1.9052 and 8.2194. So, final result is not a binary image as you formerly pointed out.

[image]

By using the formula I think is reflecting Filipponi's work, I got following result; with BAI2 values in range of -0.2981 and 0.9802 (in expected range of -1, 1; one more reason for reviewing Filipponi's formula in your code):

[image]